# Testing with PICT, but incomplete testcases

Tags: testing

I'm testing a triangle problem in PICT. I'm testing if a triangle is an equilateral triangle, an isosceles triangle,or a scalene triangle. The problem is that I never get the equilateral triangle as a result.

```
Side1:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side2:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side3:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Type:         equilateral, isosceles, scalene

IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) OR ([Side2] = [Side3]) OR ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "isosceles"  ELSE [Type] = "scalene";
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3]) AND ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "equilateral";
```

But the random thing is that when I change the last line into

```
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3]) AND ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "isosceles";
```

I randomly get values that would result in an equilateral triangle. How can I make sure I also have these values in my correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Side1:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side2:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Side3:        5,6,7,8,9,10
Type:         equilateral, isosceles, scalene

IF (([Side1] = [Side2] AND [Side2] <> [Side3]) OR ([Side2] = [Side3] AND [Side3] <> [Side1]) OR ([Side3] = [Side1] AND [Side1] <> [Side2])) THEN [Type] = "isosceles";
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3])) THEN [Type] = "equilateral";
IF ([Side1] <> [Side2] AND [Side2] <> [Side3] and [Side3] <> [Side1]) THEN [Type] = "scalene";
```

The reason is that your logic overlaps between cases, you shall explicit your conditions such as there was only one result for each case. The example above works; I validated it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *Unconditional Constraints (Invariants)* which are available in PICT.

In this case you have to substitute this line

```
IF (([Side1] = [Side2]) AND ([Side2] = [Side3]) AND ([Side3] = [Side1])) THEN [Type] = "equilateral";
```

with this one:

```
[Side1] = [Side2] and [Side2] = [Side3] and [Side3] = [Side1];
```

Therefore generated test set will contain at least 1 equilateral triangle.

Refer to documentation for details: http://www.amibugshare.com/pict/help.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yet there are 2 issues why this won't work. First if that line is true, I want 'type' to change but this doesn't happen. Second is that by adding this line these condition have to be true, so the other 2 types never occur. This is why: "An invariant declares an **ALWAYS-VALID** limitation of a domain".